# Phantomjs writes completely transparent images

Tags: phantomjs

Simple `rasterize.js` script (from phantomjs examples) on my Debian server sometimes writes completely transparent images (if it's PNG), but it have regular dimensions. It is happening most of the time, but in rare moments it makes correct image.
I can't find out why it happens.

My system:

```
Debian GNU/Linux 7.2 (wheezy) with ext4
Phantomjs 1.9.2

rendering sites: http://www.yahoo.com/ and http://phantomjs.org/
```

Script used: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js

PS: I also faced with this problem on CentOS server.

Comment: Have you tried to add delay for half of the second of so before rendering to the image? BTW, node.js tag seems irrelevant so I removed it.

Comment: It is delay in original script example.